# How to prevent duplication in dropdownlist using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How to prevent duplication in dropdownlist using JSTL .

```
<select class="abc" name="folder" >
<c:forEach items="${model.abc}" var="folder" varStatus="status">
<option value="${folder}">${folder}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Suppose my model object abc is having some data like :

Folder :"abc" , "bcd", "abc"

How to prevent abc to be populated in dropdown multiple times?

Comment: [Remove duplicates](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-remove-duplicates-elements-from-ArrayList-Java.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its never a good idea to put (even the tiniest) business logic inside your view. The responsibility of the view part of MVC is to just , well, generate the view for the end user ! No processing , no business logics involved.

So I suggest you handle duplication on the business logic end and then send the duplicate-free list over the view and display it

Answer (score 2):

Prepare your list in backend (without duplication) and display it.

Answer (score 2):

Better to remove duplicates in Java code and return a unique list to the Jsp.

If your object `abc` is an ArrayList, Convert it to Set and again back to List.
As we all know Set doesn't allow duplicates, All the duplicates in list will be removed.

Sample code:

```
    List<String> abc=new ArrayList<String>();
    abc.add("abc");
    abc.add("def");
    abc.add("abc");

    abc = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(abc));
```

Result: No duplicates in `abc`.

Comment: Thanks...Yes i got the it .